# Pushing C pointer to stack, getting table

Tags: c, lua, stack

I have two functions defined in C code:

```
static int luaMp4_load(lua_State *L){
    LPP_Mp4 *ret = LPP_Mp4Load(luaL_checkstring(L, 1));
    *pushMp4(L) = ret;
    return(1);
}
static int luaMp4_play(lua_State *L){
    LPP_Mp4Play(*toMp4(L, 1), luaL_checknumber(L, 2));
    return 0;
}
```

which are called one by one in Lua:

```
Mp4.load(movie)
Mp4:play(60)
```

Functions `pushMp4` and `toMp4` are

```
LPP_Mp4** toMp4 (lua_State *L, int index){
    LPP_Mp4** handle  = (LPP_Mp4**)lua_touserdata(L, index);
    if (handle == NULL) luaL_typerror(L, index, "Mp4");
    return handle;
}
LPP_Mp4** pushMp4(lua_State *L) {
    LPP_Mp4** newvalue = (LPP_Mp4**)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(LPP_Mp4*));
    lua_getfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, "Mp4");
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
    return newvalue;
}
```

The problem is, I'm getting a `NULL` handle in `luaMp4_play`, and it says that object in the first index of stack is `table` (while `Mp4` expected) - inside of `luaL_typerror(lua_State *L, int narg, const char *tname)`:

```
const char *msg = lua_pushfstring(L, "%s expected, got %s",
                                tname, lua_typename(L, lua_type(L,(narg))));
```

How can I get rid of it?

**Edit:**

`LPP_Mp4` struct:

```
typedef struct {
    struct mp4_read_struct reader;
    Mp4AvcNalStruct nal;
    struct mp4_video_read_output_struct v_packet;
    Mp4AvcDecoderStruct *avc;
    Mp4AvcCscStruct *csc;
} LPP_Mp4;
```

`lua_touserdata` is a Lua API library function:

```
LUA_API void *lua_touserdata (lua_State *L, int idx) {
  StkId o = index2adr(L, idx);
  switch (ttype(o)) {
    case LUA_TUSERDATA: return (rawuvalue(o) + 1);
    case LUA_TLIGHTUSERDATA: return pvalue(o);
    default: return NULL;
  }
}
```

https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/master/src/lapi.c - line 413

Comment: this line: 'LPP_Mp4** handle  = (LPP_Mp4**)lua_touserdata(L, index);' returned a NULL.   Please post the code for lua_touserdata()  and perhaps the definition of the LPP_Mp4 table

Comment: done, but I don't think it'll help somehow

Comment: `Mp4.load` *returns* your object (which you ignore). You then call `Mp4:play(60)` which uses the `Mp4` library table so `play` doesn't have a loaded movie to operate on it has a lua table (the `Mp4` module).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confused with `return(1);` in C code and had no doubt that `Mp4:load()` returns any value
Thanks to [Etan Reisner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner) for pointing to it, worked with:

```
mv = Mp4.load(movie)
mv:play(60)
```